# Dense Index Map in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary

I am having a difficulty finding a type of container, maybe the naming I am using is incorrect.

Does anyone know of a C++ container that is like std::map, but the key is of integral type. It has O(1) complexity for insertion, removal and retrieval by index.
Its iterator should iterate through the elements that are mapped by an index(key). Also it should iterate through the indexes in an ordered manner. It should be random access and have O(1) complexity to move to an arbitrary position.

I am willing to consider a case where the iterator is bidirectional and its incrementation/decrementation to be of O(1) complexity.

Comment: On a second thought, even if the iterator does not preserve the index order, is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You are asking the impossible**

`O(1)` removal,insertion,search and iteration in order will enable `O(n)` sorting by pushing all the elements, and then iterating in order.

The best algorithm known for [integer sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_sorting) is `O(n * sqrt(loglogn))`, so if we had something like you describe - it will beat the best known integer sorting algorithm.

---

**EDIT** (according to your comment on the question):

If you can do with `O(1)` search/find/insert, without guarantees on iteration order - you can use [unordered_map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/unordered_map/), which implement a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

Comment: As I said, it should be something like an std::map, where insertion is by key, here it is by index. If there is already an element with that index, it should insert nothing.

Comment: @Sogartar: It is impossible with the required complexity demands (unless you are willing to sort before iterating)

Comment: You are right, with the other requirements, iterator with O(1) complexity of ++/-- is impossible.